# Create a new folder in another directory using the name of a zip file in another directory

Tags: linux, shell, directory, subdirectory, unzip

new to shell scripting here. Currently trying to create a script that would take the name of a zip file in one directory (zipped directory) to create a new folder in another directory (unzipped directory) and then unzip the file into that new folder.

What I currently have:

`for file in ${session_path}/*.zip; do mkdir "${file%%.zip}" unzip -d "${unzipped_dir}/${file%%.zip}" "${file}" done`

It would be more ideal if I can create a script that would do what I mentioned above, but also have any folder with an "_m" go to m folder in that unzipped directory and anything with "_p" go into another folder. So the folder structure would look something like this:

zipped directory:

folder1 -> file_m1.zip
folder2 -> file_p1.zip
etc.
*each zipped file is in a separate folder in the zipped directory*

unzipped directory:

m -> file_m1 -> unzipped_file_m1 files

p -> file_p1 -> unzipped_file_p1 files

Please let me know if more clarification is needed, thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

are all files in the zip directory ending in _m1 or _p1? if so you can do an if else statement inside the for loop, and if not you can do an if else and use `continue` on one of the conditions

```
if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    case "$file" in
        *_m.zip)     echo mv "$file" "${mdir}"  ;;
        *_p.zip)     echo mv "$file" "${zdir}"  ;;
    esac
else
    echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
fi
```

something like that but make sure you define the directories in a variable before it.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help! I more so want to take the files from the zipped directory (_m and _p) , create a new folder with the names of these files in another directory containing an m and p folder and then unzip the files into those new folders. however I think it may be easier to just create a new folder with the zipped file name into the unzipped directory regardless if it's _m or _p then create another script afterward that would sort and move them. I know how to create the second script, but do you know how I would do the first part?